# Let $U_k(n)=\{x\in U(n):x\bmod k=1\}$. For $s,t\in\Bbb Z$ s.t. $\gcd(s,t)=1$, show $\beta:U_s(st)\to U(t)$ s.t. $\beta(x)=x\bmod t$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $U_k(n) = \{x \in U(n) : x \bmod k = 1\}$. For some integers $s, t$ such that $\gcd(s, t) = 1$, show that $\beta : U_s(st) \to U(t)$ defined by $\beta(x) = x \bmod t$ is an isomorphism.

Edit: I have attempted showing injectivity by having some $x, y \in U_s(st)$ such that $\beta(x) = \beta(y) \implies x \bmod t = y \bmod t$. From here, I suppose that $t$ divides $x - y$. I'm thinking that the fact that $x, y \in U_s(st)$ may have something to do with this. Am I correct in saying that $\gcd(x, s) = \gcd(y, s) = 1$? And if so, does that have to do anything with the problem?

For surjectivity, I was assuming that it might be a similar application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. The day before, I was shown a proof that $\alpha: U(st) \to U(s) \oplus U(t)$ defined by $\alpha(x) = (x \bmod s, x \bmod t)$ was an isomorphism, utilizing the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Is it applicable here?

For showing that it's a homomorphism, I don't believe I need help for that portion of the question.

Edit 2: Here is my proposed proof for the injectivity of $\beta$.

Suppose that $\beta(x) = \beta(y)$ for some $x, y \in U_s(st)$. Then $x \bmod t = y \bmod t \implies x - y \equiv 0 \bmod t \implies t|x - y$. Because any $x \in U_s(st)$ means that $x \bmod s = 1$, then $x \bmod s = y \bmod s \implies s|x - y$. Because $\gcd(s, t) = 1$, then $st|x - y \implies x \equiv y \bmod st$. Because $x, y \in U_s(st)$, then $x = y$. Hence $\beta$ is injective.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Since you don't know where to start, consider answering the following (in an [edit]): What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: @Shaun Apologies for the lack of information of my attempts; the edits I've made should hopefully reflect my current understanding of the question and any additional information.

Comment: What is $U(n)$?